# JSONObject as class attribute storage/retrieval

Tags: android

In android, I'm using model classes with methods to handle the data manipulation. My data is brought in from webservices as json. I'm contemplating the possibility of using JSONObjects to store the values of class level attributes. But, I don't know of a way to use the JSONObj as the "holder" variable and create access methods. I don't want to predetermine these methods, as jsonRepository should hold the values, not always known at design time

For example, I'd like to have:
    public class User {
    private JSONObject jsonAttributes;

```
public User(String json) { 
    this.jsonAttributes= new JSONObject(json);
}

[IMPLICIT attribute access methods]

public string Prop1() returns jsonAttributes.getString("prop1");
public string Prop1(String newProp1) returns jsonAttributes.putString("prop1",newProp1);

public string Prop2() returns jsonRepository.getString("id");
public string Prop2(String newProp2) returns jsonAttributes.putString("prop2",newProp2);
....
```

from outside this class then, I would access the attributes simply...

```
User myUser = new User(someValidJson);
String myString = myUser.Prop1
```

**Misguided? If not, how does one manage implicit property setting/getting?**

Comment: nothing prevents you from creating a user class with attributes being set from a Json and getting these fields with getter methods. What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comment above, why not create your user class, with all of the relevant memeber variables, and simply parse your JSON data in order to populate the ionformation in your user class.

There are a lot of ways you can do this, but I would consider using the [builder pattern](http://drdobbs.com/jvm/208403883?pgno=2), as it is flexible, which could be useful if your JSON data changes in the future.

Comment: for ref. to the builder pattern, thx. I opted for local SQLite storage instead and a service to retrieve JSON and populate the db.